# Why can't `find` actually find all of the directories matching a pattern?

Tags: regex, unix, find

I have directories matching the pattern `foo[0-9]+` and `foo-bar`. I want to remove all directories matching the former pattern. My goal for doing this is by using `find`, but when I try to find directories matching the former pattern, I can't recall them:

```
$ mkdir foo{1..15} foo-bar
$ # yields nothing
$ find . -name "foo[0-9]+"
```

When I try to find everything that matches `foo[^-]`, only some of the directories appear:

```
$ find . -name "foo[^-]"
./foo9
./foo7
./foo6
./foo1
./foo8
./foo4
./foo3
./foo2
./foo5
```

I've played with the `-regex` flag and all available `-regextype`s, but can't seem to get the magic right.

How can I list all of these directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/foo[0-9]+'
```

You might want to limit the type: `find -E . -type d -regex '.*/foo[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$ ls -F
foo-bar/  foo10/  foo12/  foo14/  foo2/  foo4/  foo6/  foo8/
foo1/     foo11/  foo13/  foo15/  foo3/  foo5/  foo7/  foo9/

$ find . -name "foo[^-]*"
./foo1
./foo2
./foo3
./foo4
./foo5
./foo6
./foo7
./foo8
./foo9
./foo10
./foo11
./foo12
./foo13
./foo14
./foo15
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to list all directories that don't match `foo-bar` then you can simply use the `-not` operator:

```
$ find . -not -name foo-bar
.
./foo1
./foo2
./foo3
./foo4
./foo5
./foo6
./foo7
./foo8
./foo9
./foo10
./foo11
./foo12
./foo13
./foo14
./foo15
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you were using file globbing and not regexes when you weren't using the -regex flag.

To find the files using globbing:

```
find . -name "foo[1-9]" -o -name "foo1[0-5]" -o -name "foo-bar"
```

There we match any files with name "foo" followed by "single digit between 1 and 9", or files named foo1 followed by "single digit between 0 and 5", or files named exactly "foo-bar".

Or if you know the directory won't have any numbered files aside from the ones you created:

```
find . -name "foo[1-9]*" -o -name "foo-bar'"
```

Here we find all files named "foo" followed by one digit, followed by any number of any characters, or the file named exactly foo-bar.  Globbing is not very precise like regexes, but it's often sufficient and it's pretty quick.

The * and ? in globbing is different than in regexes.  In globbing, they themselves represent unknown characters in the string being matched as well as the quantity of them.  In regexes, they modify the previous atom in the regex, and express the quantity of that previous atom.